# Why does all colors and effects not export to unity?

Tags: texturing, uv, unity, color

[image]

Why do all colors and effects not export to unity? All the white shading on edges and the brown color does not show in unity? I'm using a color palette where I scale the UV to 0 and then use g to move around on each face.

Comment: You would have to bake the shaders before the export, also add the same hdri in unity. BTW: Please take the [tour] to learn about how this site works, thanks.

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures/57541#57541